# Parse Sign Up for Application ID and Client ID for Swift

Tags: parse-platform

Hi there im having problems signing into parse i need the application and client ID to create my chat app for swift can anyone help me? please reply soon!

Comment: I've tried the open source code for parse need help on how to make that work

Answer (score 0):

Parse is closing down so you can't now signup for a new account. You need to either choose another service or host the now open-source parse platform yourself (or use another service which will host it for you).